# Is there any way to create multiple databases in one Amazon RDS database instance from CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I want to create different databases in single Amazon RDS instance.

I know it's possible manually to create a RDS DB instance with one database from CloudFormation and connect from some tool (eg SQL Workbench) and then create a new Database.

But I want to create through CloudFormation multiple databases under one DB instance.

Comment: What is "CFT"? Are you referring to a CloudFormation Template?

Comment: Yes, CFT means CloudFormation Template to create AWS stack

Answer (score 1):

AWS CloudFormation can create a **stack** of resources from a **template** that describes those resources.

This includes **Amazon RDS** database instances.

However, CloudFormation **cannot create the logical databases *within* an RDS instance** because this requires commands to actually be run *on* the DB instance itself.

CloudFormation merely calls the AWS APIs that create the database instance -- operations within the database are outside the scope of AWS APIs and are dependent upon the specific database.

Once CloudFormation has created the DB instance, you would need to connect to the database, authenticate and then run appropriate `CREATE DATABASE` commands.

Comment: I don't think that's right, at least for MySQL instances. If I use CloudFormation to create an RDS instance and specify the following property in the CF JSON - "DBName": "test" - then I get a MySQL instance with that database already created.